# Unable to find command: cordova start app_name blank

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic3, javac

I am trying to create an Ionic app. But I can't create the app folder.
I have installed Ionic, Cordova and also java sdk

===================================

PS D:\hybrid> ionic info
[WARN] **You are not in an Ionic project directory**. Project context may be missing.

cli packages: (C:\Users\Suman\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
```

System:

```
Node : v10.6.0
npm  : 6.1.0
OS   : Windows 8.1
```

Misc:

## backend : pro

==================================

PS D:\hybrid> cordova -v

## 8.0.0

=================================

PS D:\hybrid> javac -version
javac 1.8.0_171

===================================

Now I am trying to run this command 
ionic cordova start helloWorld2 blank

But getting this error

[ERROR] Unable to find command: cordova start helloWorld2 blank

```
    You may need to be in an Ionic project directory.
```

Please let me know how I can overcome this issue.

Comment: You really should read the docs: https://ionicframework.com/getting-started
The command is `ionic start helloWorld2 blank`

Comment: After exactitude that command it's asking me "? Would you like to integrate your new app with Cordova to target native iOS and Android? (y/N)". After that if I entered any of (Y/N)  it's gets struck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try uninstalling your current NodeJS version and reinstalling version 8.~ and then run

> ionic start HelloWorld2 blank

then enter Y when asked if you want to integrate the app with Cordova.

[Download link for NodeJS v8.11.3](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/release/v8.11.3/)